# ASP.NET Web API split response in chuncks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

Is it possible to split a response from WEB API into chunks as follow.

I have a win forms app that can handle 100 KB of data at a time.

When this client makes a request to my ASP.NET WEB API for some data let's assume that the WEB API response is 2 MB ... can I somehow cache this response, split it in 100KB chunks and return the first chunk to my app. That response will contain a link/token to the next chunk and so forth? Does this sound crazy? Is this feasible?

One more question: when we are talking about request/response content length (size), what does this means: that the content itself cannot be bigger then 100 KB or the content with headers and so on ... I want to know if headers are included or not in the content length?

Example: if my response is 99KB and the headers are 10 KB (109 KB) will this pass if the limit is 100KB?

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is a pretty common solution to large data sets in webservices. Facebook, for example, will paginate API results when they exceed a certain number of rows. Your idea for locally caching the full result is a good optimization, though you can probably get away with not caching it as a first implementation if you are unsure of whether or not you will keep this as your final solution.

Without caching, you can just pass the page number and total number of pages back to your client, and it can then re-make the call with a specific page number in mind for the next set. This makes for an easy loop on the client, and your data access layer is marginally more complicated since it will only re-serialize certain row numbers depending on the page parameter, but that should still be pretty simple.

Web API has access to the same `HttpRuntime.Cache` object as the rest of the ASP.NET project types do, so it should be easy to write a wrapper around your data access call and stick the result of a larger query into that cache. Use a token as the key to that value in the cache and pass the key, likely an instance of the `GUID` class, back to the client with the current page number. On subsequent calls, skip accessing your normal persistence method (DB, file, etc) and instead access the `GUID` key in the `HttpRuntime.Cache` and find the appropriate row. One wrinkle with this is if you have multiple webservers hosting your service since the `HttpRuntime.Cache` will exist on only the machine that took the first call, so unless your load balancer has IP affinity or you have a distributed caching layer, this will be more difficult to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. The web api will be hosted in azure and i'm thinking to make use of azure caching for this.